# escape html 4.0 greek characters in .NET

Tags: c#, html, character-encoding, escaping

I need a similar method in .NET to `escapeHTML` from Java that escapes plain text with special Greek symbols, less-than or equal to, identical to, or any other math character. I have a plain text like `a ≤ b` and i want to escape it to HTML entities `a &le; b`

Comment: '≤' is not a greek symbol. It is a math symbol.

Comment: A better solution would be simply to ensure that you're sending the correct encoding for the text that you're transmitting. For example, if your text is encoded in UTF-8, you would want to send the appropriate HTTP header (or meta tag) to tell the user agent how to decode it. This way any non-ASCII characters can be left as they are, without the need to convert them into HTML entities.

Comment: yes. i mean mathematical symbols. they are in the same category with greek letters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
HtmlEncode() and HtmlDecode()
```

Theses methods are avaibles in `System.Web.HttpUtility` namespace

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx

Comment: `HtmlEncode` won't replace arbitrary non-ASCII characters (e.g. `≤`) with their corresponding HTML entities; it only escapes characters that are reserved in HTML.